# line breaks in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

we develop the sql scripts in oracle sql developer and in production dba execute the same in oracle sql plus.

The problem is if we insert a line break

```
  Create table test(

  text number(10)
```

The line break is causing the scripts to fail, do you know how to fix this in sqlplus?

Also we generate the scripts using liquibase, so any ways to address this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding:

```
set sqlblanklines on
```

to the start of your sql script.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the line break, it's the empty line that causes the problem:

```
Create table test(
       -- here you have it
  text number(10)
```

The solution is simple - delete the empty line.

Comment: Yes it will work if I delete empty line but it is autogenerated and it is difficult ot enforce there will not be empty this work fine in toad and sql developer, so just want to see how to ensure sql plus ignore blank lines adn work fine like sql developer and toad.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. OldProgrammer has a perfect solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Double new lines mean usually line ending incompatibility. I guess your script has \r\n windows line endings, but you try to execute the script in unix environment where \n is the expected line ending. There are tools to convert between the different line endings, but hopefully you can easily change it in your editor.